# Formatting rows in Quasar Table based on prop item

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

Using q-table I'm trying to format specific rows based on the `name` it contains, however somehow the table is not being displayed when I add computed `class` as class binding.
Is there a way to make it work so that multiple conditions for class binding can be used?

Here
https://codepen.io/pokepim/pen/wvGWNEp
You can see that the table is not loading when this computed class binding is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your codes invoked `this.props.row.name` inside computed property is wrong usage.

The context of computed property is the instance of current component, not `q-tr` context, so `this.props.row` doesn't exist.

The correct usage will be pass `props.name` of `v-slot:body="props"` into one method, inside that method returns the class name you expected based on different conditions.

For example ([The codepen](https://codepen.io/cj2018work/pen/QWNEXGY)):

**The template:**

```
  <template v-slot:body="props">
    <q-tr :props="props"  :class="tableFormat(props.row.name)">
      <q-td v-for="col in props.cols" :key="col.name" :props="props">{{ col.value }}</q-td>
    </q-tr>
  </template>
```

**The scripts:**

```
{
  methods: {
    tableFormat: function (name) {
      return name ? 'text-bold' : ''
    }
  }
}
```